# Which physics to chose for character (NSFW content)?

Tags: animation, rigging, physics, cloth-simulation, soft-body

Sorry for a naive question, but I'm a total newbie in blender and doing my first animation pipeline.
The whole character body is single mesh about 35k+ faces.
So which body physics is more preferable for NSFW content the "cloth physics" or the "soft body" one ?
And should I subdivide my mesh for about 1 or 2 steps for better animation quality ?
Again thanks for an answers, and sorry if they were delivered incorrectly.

Comment: Hello, your question lacks details, what kind of effect are you trying to achieve? It will help to choose between Cloth and Soft Body. As forthe subdivision, itwon't increase the animation quality, it will make the object look rounder, but it will also make the calculation longer

Comment: For the most part the characters body collisions effects and also penetrations effects with preserving a body elasticity and forms.

Comment: Cloth physics is, essentially, soft body physics, with some extra parameters.  If you learn the params, cloth is probably better.  Subdivision is often wise, but the question is where/when; it's not wise when performance is of utmost importance; it's less wise when you don't yet understand subdivision topology.  In future, recommend separating multiple questions, like these, into multiple BSE questions.

Comment: Very thanks for an answers )